# JMeter JMS Point-to-Point Sampler with ActiveMQ

Tags: java, jmeter, activemq-classic

We are upgrading an application to use ActiveMQ (classic, version 5.15.9).
Hence, we are aligning our existing JMeter (version 3.1) tests to use ActiveMQ. In the JMS Sampler, the properties have been modified and set as follow:

- Initial Context Factory =
  org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
- Context Provider Url = tcp://[MyHost]:61616
- Queue Connection Factory = ConnectionFactory
- Send Queue = queue.MyApp.RequestQueue
- Receive Queue = queue.MyApp.ResponseQueue

Still, I get the following error in the JMeter logs (even though functional tests work with that ActiveMQ stand-alone and queues):

> ERROR - **jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.JMSSampler: queue.MyApp.RequestQueue javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: queue.MyApp.RequestQueue**
>
> > at org.apache.activemq.jndi.ReadOnlyContext.lookup(ReadOnlyContext.java:235)
> >
> > at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
> >
> > at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.JMSSampler.threadStarted(JMSSampler.java:337)
> >
> > at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:659)
> >
> > at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:996)
> >
> > at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:978)
> >
> > at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:628)
> >
> > at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:616)
> >
> > at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:245)
> >
> > at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Any thought on what I may have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure [JMS Point-to-Point Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Point-to-Point) a little bit differently, to wit:

1. JNDI name Request queue: `Q.REQ`
2. JNDI name Receive queue: `Q.RSP`
3. Add the following JNDI properties:

   - `queue.Q.RSP` with the value of `queue.MyApp.ResponseQueue`
   - `queue.Q.REQ` with the value of `queue.MyApp.RequestQueue`

Full configuration just in case:

[image]

More information: [Building a JMS Testing Plan - Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter/)

Demo:

[image]

Comment: It seems I have found the same information from another sources. It has the advantage to confirm the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got looking to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jmeter/jmeter_jms_pointtopoint_test_plan.htm to find the solution to my issue.

As in this tutorial, I set:

- Send Queue = Q.REQ
- Receive Queue = Q.RESP

Then, I added JNDI Properties as follow:

- Name = queue.Q.REQ, value = queue.MyApp.RequestQueue
- Name = queue.Q.RESP, value = queue.MyApp.RequestQueue

And Voila!